# How to interpret the lastErrorObject properties returned from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB sometimes return a `lastErrorObject` - and as far as I can read this is its schema:

```
{
  updatedExisting: <boolean>,
  upserted: <boolean>,
  n: <num>,
  connectionId: <num>,
  err: <string>,
  ok: <num>
}
```

But the only place on the mongodb.org website I can find any reference to this object is buried in the [findAndModify API documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

But nowhere can I find any explanation of the different properties of the object. I can make educated guesses, but even what I can make out from the documentation seems to contradict it self. Like for instance `upserted`, which according to findAndModify should be a boolean, but apparently also can be an `ObjectId`.

And what is `ok`? It seems to be `1` most of the time - but it's not a boolean, so can it be `2` and what does that mean?

Even though some of the properties might be pretty self-explanatory, please write an explanation for each in your answer so it's 100% documented for everybody. Or if I just missed it (it happens), feel free to link to the documentation where this is explained ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have all posible return values in this [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/)

But I agree with you. Sometimes MongoDB documentation is quite messy.

Comment: Thanks. As for the `ok` and the `upserted` property, it seems the MongoDB docs just isn't that actuate. As I interpret it, `ok` is a number representing a boolean (`0` = `false` and `1` = `true`) even though it's sometimes referred to as a real boolean (like `updatedExisting`), and `upserted` is an ObjectID, even though it's sometimes referred to as a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

The last error in mongodb is used to return a "status of last operation".

[getLastError](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/) is used a lot by drivers to get feedback on the operations sent for execution. I believe that documentation should help you.

Comment: Thanks - I would accept your answer too if possible. @rubenfa beat you by 2 minutes ;)

Comment: Do you know why it's called 'lastErrorObject' if it returns the status of the last operation, i.e. it's not necessarily an error?