# Unable to update data values on mongoDb native findOneAndUpdate query

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, updates

```
exports.update_activity_status = (req, res) => {
  const {
    campaign_id,
    leadId,
    leadActivity,
    status,
  } = req.body;

  const client = mongoClient.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URL}`, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  client.then((cli) => {
    cli
      .db(`${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}`)
      .collection(`${process.env.ACTIVITY_COLLECTION}`)
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          "data.campaign_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(campaign_id),
          "data.leads.$._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(leadId),
          // "data.leads._id" : leadId
        },
        {
          $set: {
            "data.leads.$.leadActivity": leadActivity,
            "data.leads.$.status": status,
          },
        },
        {
          returnNewDocument: true,
        }
      )
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("UPDATED RESULT", result);
        res.json(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("new err", err));
  });
};
```

In my query, I need to update the status and leadActivity of the users whose `leadId` matches the following conditions:

1. campaign_id that matches the document (this is working fine).
2. leadsId that matches inside that particular document (not working).

First I tried using only `db.find({"data.campaign_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(campaign_id)})` and it returns me the data that matches only the first condition as specified above. As soon as I try it along with second condition and `findOneAndUpdate({....})`, accessing the nested data after including secondary filter condition returns `null`.

Here's is what my document object looks like:

[image]
Any help to resolve this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second condition for matching the `_id` in the `leads`-array is incorrect, you need to change it to:

```
  "data.leads._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(leadId)
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks for pointing out this silly issue of mine :)

Comment: Just one more last thing. It is returning something like `"lastErrorObject": {
        "n": 1,
        "updatedExisting": true
    },` along with the updated record. Can you help explain what's this about? Is it some error ?

Comment: I think it's just some info about the last operation and not an actual error as long as `lastErrorObject.err` is undefined/null -> check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624486/how-to-interpret-the-lasterrorobject-properties-returned-from-mongodb/21624686
or here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLastError/